# Devel kpr, dpr, dpm, etc. only print after cache flush

Tags: 7, debugging

I'm writing a small module and using the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) print functions (dpr, kpr, dpm, etc.) to print out some values.

However, I only see the values in the page after I flush certain caches. if I just reload the page or go to it I see nothing. This is true for both the message-area and the regular debug print functions. Is this expected?

I am logged in as admin so I'd think ordinary page caching is off.

(This is in D7.)

Comment: It all depends on where your inserting your debug code as to whether or not it's cached. For example if your adding debug to a custom input filter then that will always be cached regardless of your admin user or not. Can you include an example function of where your adding the debug?

Comment: Thanks. It's in a hook: hook_field_widget_info_alter(). The idea is to augment an existing field widget. I'm just getting started, and am using the Devel print functions to see its arg.

Comment: From what I can remember from D6 all field widgets are cached so it's possible that this is expected behaviour.

Comment: _info is definely cache for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hook_field_widget_info_alter() is cached.  Follow these steps to [Suppress caching (for development) or to use an external page cache](http://drupal.org/node/797346)

> when developing for Drupal you might want to suppress all caching of
>   data to make sure new hooks, theme functions, etc are recognized
>   immediately.
>
> This will have performance detriments, of course, so must not be used
>   in production. To turn on this development mode, add the following to
>   your Drupal 7 settings.php file: